# Solidity code for getting raw data from blockchain based on blocknumber/Hash

Tags: solidity

will you please make a video/code or any samples for solidity code based on block number/Hash to get Raw data which is stored in Blockchain.And also please help if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such functions in solidity to get raw block data.
But have a look on this [Official documentation link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) which will help to get block info

> **blockhash**(uint blockNumber) returns (bytes32): hash of the given block
>   
>  **block.coinbase** (address payable): current block miner’s address
>   
>  **block.difficulty** (uint): current block difficulty 
>   **block.gaslimit** (uint): current block gaslimit 
>  **block.number**
>   (uint): current block number 
>  **block.timestamp** (uint): current
>   block timestamp as seconds since unix epoch

Comment: Ok,Thanks for the reply and I have one  doubt if I send data using unique id first time I given id=100 name="lucky",and again id =100 name="sonu" while getting the data it giving latest one. Is there any possibility for not allowing the same id twice in blockchain.

Comment: As per my understanding, i am assuming that you are replacing the value, you could use array to store the values.
Provide your code sample, it helps to understand what you are doing and to resolve issue

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Product
{
    struct ProductInfo
    {
       uint256 id;
       string jsoninfo;
    }
     
    mapping (uint256 => ProductInfo) productsList;
    
    function writeInfo(uint256 idL,string memory infoL )  public
    {
       
       ProductInfo storage pin=productsList[idL];
      
       pin.id=idL;
       pin.jsoninfo=infoL;

    }
       
    function getInfo(uint256 idL) public view returns (string memory)
    {
   
       return productsList[idL].jsoninfo;
     
    } 
   
    }

Comment: as you have said it is unique id, it will be only one and you are using mapping to store value. So if you are passing same id again info will be replaced. To restrict it you can place a boolean check in ProductInfo.

Comment: Try this code : pragma solidity ^0.5.0;contract Product{struct ProductInfo{uint256 id; string jsoninfo; bool valueCheck;}mapping (uint256=> ProductInfo) productsList;function writeInfo(uint256 idL,string memory infoL ) public{require(!productsList[idL].valueCheck);ProductInfo storage pin=productsList[idL];pin.id=idL;pin.jsoninfo=infoL;pin.valueCheck=true;}function getInfo(uint256 idL) public view returns (string memory){return productsList[idL].jsoninfo;}}